# which API is used to create publicities in facebook?

Tags: flutter, facebook-ads-api

i am developping a mobile app which can use the facebook API to create and diffuse publicities. but i don't know which API to use. i saw somewhere th MARKETING API can be the one but i am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The markeying API is one choice. However, there also exists the Facebook Ads API. The only problem with this one is that you have to be approved and verified by Facebook to use it.